# Gifts and Party Members

Tags: dragon-age-origins

I am finding a slew of gifts throughout my journeys. Which ones are most appropriate for which party members?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Some items (like Alistair's Mother's Amulet) you know by the plot whom you should give them.

For the others:

- Alistair: statuettes
- Dog: bones
- Leliana: church (Andraste) stuff
- Morrigan: jewelry
- Oghren: booze
- Shale: gems
- Sten: paintings
- Zevran: silver/gold bars

A complete list can be found [here](https://dragonage.fandom.com/wiki/Gifts_(Origins)).

Answer (score 6):

The [Dragon Age Wiki](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Gifts) has an excellent write up on the gift system as well as which gifts goto which party member.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat tangentially, the [Golden Mirror](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Golden_Mirror) is especially significant if you want a [complex relationship arc with Morrigan](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Morrigan#Epilogue.28s.29_acquisition):

> If you have previously broken up with Morrigan, giving her the mirror can restart the romance . . .
>
> If you are planning to get the 'ring' epilogue for Morrigan at the end of Origins, and import the same file to Awakening and get the elusive 'Dark-haired sorceress Morrigan' epilogue, it is advised (although not required) to save this item and not to give it until the epilogue auto-save.
>
> . . . The tricky part is how to import the same character to Awakening and get the 'basic' Morrigan slide at the end of that campaign. The problem with the final Morrigan dialogue at Denerim's city gate is that Morrigan will invariably end the relationship, which alters their status to 'Friendly' at most. . .

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Wynne has a passion for wine and books, in case you were wondering.

Alistair likes runestones too. The dog loves you already so there is no need to give him bones, unless you want a codex update.